# Pegar valor selecionando de um combobox e enviar para um capo php

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Vem uma consulta de produto do banco, e sera colocada em um combobox, tenho que exibir a unidade de medida (que está na mesma tabela no BD) em um campo de texto, apos o usuário selecionar o produto.

Obs: utilizo o framework laravel (na ultima versão).

```
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('55')) has-error @endif">
                                                {{ Form::text('55',$ordemCompra->ferramenta_id, array('class' => 'form-control', 'readonly'  => TRUE )) }}
                                                @if ($errors->has('55'))
                                                    <span class="help-block">
                                                    <strong>
                                                        {{ $errors->first('55') }}
                                                    </strong>
                                                </span>
                                                @endif
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
```

codigo, esse ferramnta é o produto.

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra alternativa é

```
<td>
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('55')) has-                 error @endif">
        <form action={{   suarota() }}>
            <input type="text" maxlength="55" name="ferramenta_id" value={{ $ordemCompra->ferramenta_id }} readonly/>
        </form>
         <span class="help-block">
         <strong>
             {{ $errors->first('55') }}
         </strong>
         </span>
         @endif
        </div>
       </div>
      </td>
```